# Quickest way to do set subtraction on list of tuples based on multiple equalities?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**The problem:**  I have two large lists that have some overlapping data.  I want to subtract the overlapping data from the larger of the two lists, a list I call `restoredBottles` in my code.  The second smaller list I am using is called `allBottles`.  Given their size, restarting my inner loop each iteration of the outerloop was taking me over 3 days to complete.  I need to try to do a sliding window.

**Result I want**:  After the loops are finished, I would like to have the list `restoredBottles` only contain the data that was not overlapping.

**Both lists are ordered by timestamps in ascending order.**

```
for productsAndArchiveIndex, (idx, bcode, tstamp, parentPrepackId, prepackBarcode, tableName) in enumerate(allBottles):
    for restoredDataIndex, (barcode, timestamp, prepack, workorder) in enumerate(restoredBottles):
        # Step 4:  Is this in products+productsArchive_archive?
        if bcode==barcode and tstamp == timestamp and prepackBarcode == prepack:

            # Step 5:  If so, delete it from
            # restoredBottles, if not, move on
            del restoredBottles[restoredDataIndex]
            i = restoredDataIndex - 1
            #Let's shorten this list, we know we are in date order so if we just go back until we hit an earlier time, we can slice it from there
            #If we have room to go backwards
            if i > 0:
                currTimestamp = timestamp
                timeStampToLeft = restoredBottles[i][1]
                #No need to do this towards the end, might only give us a index out of range error
                goodToSlice = False
                while timeStampToLeft >= currTimestamp and i > 0:

                    i -= 1
                    timeStampToLeft = restoredBottles[i][1]
                    goodToSlice = True

                #Then it makes sense to slice
                if i > 0  and goodToSlice:
                    restoredBottles = restoredBottles[i:]

            break
        elif tstamp < timestamp:
            #print(str(tstamp)+ " is farther in the future than "+str(timestamp)+", can stop search")
            #since this is an ordered list, there is no reason to keep searching
            break
```

I just realized why my result is so short is that I am literally only getting the tail end of the list of my `restoredBottles` list since I am deleting everything before the shared part.  I need to use the indices in my for loop so I can delete the item, but to make this work reasonably quickly, I need to start my second for loop at a more reasonable index than the beginning again (restored bottles is about 2.5 million items long, allBottles is about 1.9, so end of the day I should have around ~600,000 remaining in restored bottles, to be written to a CSV).  Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: On a positive note, you can edit the question and make it more crisp. That will create ease of understanding and also interest to solve.

Comment: Simplified the question.

Comment: @bjk116, First, I suggest that you prepare sample data on a smaller scale.It might help you test your own code changes. Second,posting the sample data, with expected output, will help people trying to help you on this program. Third, slicing inside the inner `for` loop is wrong (as you've realized) and performs unnecessary copy of your huge list. Instead, build a list called to_be_del_indices based on your overlap-detection. Then, loop thru your big list one last time to del the items at those indices. Fourth: Note that enumerate has an optional "start" arg. Use it for your inner `for` loop.

Comment: Was unaware of the start in the enumerate function, that is helpful thanks.  I had thought of doing the  to_be_del list idea.  Instead I ended up settling on making a list of `missingbottles`=[] before the first loop, and in the 
`if i>0 and timeStampToLeft < currTimestamp: 

missingBottles=missingBottles+restoredBottles[:i] /* since they are definitely not overlapped*/


restoredBottles = restoredBottles[i:]`

Comment: With the answer below, could your lists be sets instead? It would be much faster to work with sets since it is extremely easy to remove duplicates (though converting a your lists to sets in this method would take a lot of time).  The other option is to work with dataframes and treat it like a database and just query what you want.  Depending on your project, using a small local database (such as sqlalchemy) may be a viable option then you can query data however you want it and never have to deal with repetitive data.

Comment: Here's the issue.  I have duplicates of many data but I can't wipe out from a single instance.  I am currently using mysql, that's how I am generating the lists in the first place.

Here's the biggest issue for me, I can have something like this ("barcode1", 10/10/2018 10:10:10, prepackId1) appear 5 times in my restoredBottles list and that means 5 bottles with a similar ending barcode were scanned in the same second (which has happened).  And in my allBottles, only have that appear once, I only want to delete once instance then.

Answer (score 0):

May want to try converting the lists into "sets" and doing a "difference" operation on them. Keep in mind the set operation will remove any duplicates in the list and also the order.

You would need to re-sort the end result.

```
>>>a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]

>>>b = [3, 4, 5, 5, 6]
>>>list(set(a) - set(b))
[1, 2]
```

[python sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)